# Changing time format into readable format for as.yearmon

Tags: r, date

I have the following problem.

My dates look like this: `2006 01` where 2006 is the year and 01 is the month. Basically my format looks like this **YYYY mm**. The problem is, that `as.yearmon` only gives me NA values when I try to use the following code:

```
as.yearqtr(as.yearmon(dates) + 1/12)
```

And gives those NA values to `as.yearqtr`.

When the dates looked like this `Jan 2006`, there were no problems.
Is it possible to change `%Y %m` to `%b %Y`? This means `2006 01` to `Jan 2006`.

Basically, with this code, you can create a time index which is useful, when you want to use the meteorological nomenclature to create seasonal means, for instance:

```
zApply(df.rasterbrick, by = as.yearqtr(as.yearmon(df.rasterbrick@z$date) + 1/12), fun = mean)
```

January in the time index becomes for instance February, February March and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be enough if you make use of the `format` argument in `as.yearmon`.

```
require(zoo)
as.yearqtr(as.yearmon("2006 01", format = "%Y %m"))
# [1] "2006 Q1"
```

In effect, you could also do:

```
as.yearqtr("2006 01", format = "%Y %m")
# [1] "2006 Q1"
```

if you are only interested in quarters. Naturally, you at liberty to offset your data as you please:

```
>> as.yearqtr("2006 01", format = "%Y %m") + 6/12
# [1] "2006 Q3"
```

*or*

```
as.yearqtr(as.yearmon("2006 01", format = "%Y %m") + 6/12)
# [1] "2006 Q3"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've used the first option. I've used format everywhere else, but not in `as.yearmon` directly, while its so obvious. Cheers.